# Angular Material custom theme on dialog, snackbar,...entryComponents

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using Angular & Material v6 and I have a question about the application of a custom theme on entryComponents like dialog or snack bar.

Actually, I put the Roboto font on all component using the custom theme of material but it is not applied to my dialog or snack-bar.

[You can find a stackblitz example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bhndhg)

As you can see, the Roboto font is correctly applied on my page but if you open the dialog, the Time New Roman is used instead...

I just:

- fork the example of dialog from angular material website.
- add a custom theme.scss (using Roboto) and include it in angular-cli.json
- remove the global font-family in style.css

Any advises, explanations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your app you need to apply your typography to the application page body so that all components automatically inherit from it including the overlay component that holds the dialog. In the stackblitz demo, you commented that out to test your typography:

```
body { 
    /* font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; */
    margin: 0;
}
```

So you either need to replace that in your theme file with something like:

```
body {
    font-family: mat-font-family($custom-typography);
    margin: 0;
}
```

Or (you can't do this when using stackblitz) use the Angular Material typography class in your main index.html page:

```
<body class="mat-typography">
    ...
</body>
```

Also, your typography configuration needs to define sizes and weight for all of the typography levels used by Angular Material. An easy way to simply modify the default configuration is using a SASS merge. For example:

```
$custom-typography: map-merge(
    mat-typography-config(), 
    mat-typography-config(
        $font-family: 'Roboto, sans-serif'
    )
);
```

This takes your definitions and writes them over the default configuration, leaving anything you didn't re-define intact.

And you only need to call `mat-core()` alone as it will call `angular-material-typography()` which in turn calls `mat-base-typography()`.